# How to obtain the value of a PHP variable through a SQL Query?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I'm currently working on a challenge problem which asks for you to submit a SQL Query in order to obtain an answer. However, it isn't a simple SQL injection, as the PHP source code has a little safeguard that only outputs an answer when a certain input is given. Here is the code below:

```
<?php
     include "config.php";
     ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
     ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

     $answer = $_POST["answer"];
     $debug = $_POST["debug"];
     $query = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE answer='$answer'";
     echo "<pre>";
     echo "SQL query: ", htmlspecialchars($query), "\n";
     echo "</pre>";
 ?>
```

This simply outputs the SQL query I put in. Below it is the safeguard:

```
 <?php
    $con = new SQLite3($database_file);
    $result = $con->query($query);

    $row = $result->fetchArray();
    if($answer == $CANARY)  {
      echo "<h1>Perfect!</h1>";
      echo "<p>Your flag is: $FLAG</p>";
    }
    elseif ($row) {
      echo "<h1>You are so close.</h1>";
    } else {
      echo "<h1>Wrong.</h1>";
    }
  ?>
```

My theory is that one can display the value of $CANARY through the SQL Query, with the line that says `echo "SQL query: ", htmlspecialchars($query), "\n";` However, I am at odds of how to do so.

I understand that there is a similar question about this challenge, but I think that doesn't really ask for how to put the PHP part into the SQL, just how to perform a SQL injection. My knowledge of PHP is limited, as I basically started learning it today when I started this problem; potentially this is a PHP injection?

Thanks to whoever can help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. SQL injection can be.
For example, if set

```
$answer = "'; DELETE FROM answers WHERE ''='";
```

your code delete answers table

You need use

```
SQLite3::escapeString($answer)
```

And construction

```
$row = $result->fetchArray();
```

get array of values from table answers, and you need compare value from array, as i think

Comment: I think the problem with that is that I can't change the phps, so I have to make the $CANARY display right away from the initial SQL query.